# RewriteRule will not work in .htaccess file

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have found several questions on Stack that have show lots and lot of examples, but I have tried everyone in the book and this refuses to work.

I am trying to convert.

```
www.domain.com/title/index.php?id=70048305
```

to

```
www.domain.com/title/70048305
```

I want it to be converted both ways.  When they type in with the query string and with the clean url.

What is wrong with my rewrite?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^title/(.+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I should note that I've placed this .htaccess file both on the root and in the /title/ folder.

Comment: are you trying it on your localhost? When I usually edit `.htaccess` on localhost, it takes like 10-15 mins to come into action. Sometimes even a restart on apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-+/]+)$ index.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-+/]+)/$ index.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Spot on, I was coming back in here to answer my own question.  The first one is the one that works.

Answer (score 0):

Don't match `^title/(.+)$` you need to be matching only numbers like so `^title/([\d]+)/?`

Otherwise,

```
www.domain.com/title/index.php?id=70048305
```

will match and be redirected to:

```
index.php?id=index.php?id=70048305
```