# Hide .php extension with url rewriting using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following url `http://www.example.com/teams.php?team_id=12`
I want this url to be `http://www.example.com/teams-pavilion-boys-varsity-soccer`

I have tried the following code

```
Options +FollowSymlinks    
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^teams-([0-9a-zA-Z]+)\.html$ teams.php?team_id=$1
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of "please help me" you could have explained how it's misbehaving, or what you're stumbling on. (Guessing the incomplete charclass / absent url suffix, and expecting numeric id's to materialize from strings.)

Comment: What exactly happened when you tried with your code? Or in other words `what is not working`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RewriteRule will not work in .htaccess file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354509/rewriterule-will-not-work-in-htaccess-file)

Comment: possible duplicate of [rewrite ?id=__ to page title stored in db row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789567/rewrite-id-to-page-title-stored-in-db-row)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html

I suggest passing the `team_name` instead of the `team_id` or you can figure out the `team_name` from the id. I would even pass in all of the things you need like 'town' 'gender' 'rank' 'sport'

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^teams-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ teams.php?team_name=$1
```

Or

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^teams-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ teams.php?team_town=$1&team_gender=$2&team_rank=$3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ [URLHERE] [NC]
```

[WATCH THIS](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZw4XJuRw3U)